# Is there a R function to sort a data frame

Tags: r

I tried to sort the following data frame. But I get error like

```
sort(test,decreasing = TRUE)
```

> Error in `[.data.frame`(x, order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)) : 
>     undefined columns selected"

```
   test <- data.frame(x = c(26, 21, 20), y = c(34, 29, 28))
   sort(test$y,decreasing = TRUE)
   [1] 34 29 28
```

But I need

```
    x  y
 1 20 28
 2 21 29
 3 26 34
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `order` to get the index and use that to order to rows of data

```
test[order(test$y),]
#   x  y
#3 20 28
#2 21 29
#1 26 34
```

---

`sort` returns the sorted values.  If we need the index as well, use `index.return = TRUE` (by default it is `FALSE`), then it would return a `list` of vectors - values and 'ix' for the index.  Extract the index and use for ordering

Comment: Perfect thanks. But just to for the information, what if it other way round. I need to sort descending?

Comment: @JanaP  Either you can use that argument or just `order(-test$y)`

Answer (score 1):

You need decreasing as `FALSE` not `TRUE`:

```
test[sort(test$y, decreasing = FALSE,index.return=TRUE)[[2]],]
   x  y
3 20 28
2 21 29
1 26 34
```